# Populating FirebaseIndexRecyclerAdapter with a list of Keys in an ArrayList instead of Query

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Is it possible to use the FirebaseIndexRecyclerAdapter with a list of keys that are in an ArrayList? instead of using the key Query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FirebaseIndexRecyclerAdapter` has only `two constructors` according to the FirebaseUI FirebaseRecyclerViewAdapter class [official documentation](https://firebaseui.com/docs/android/index.html?com/firebase/ui/FirebaseRecyclerViewAdapter.html).

```
FirebaseRecyclerViewAdapter(java.lang.Class<T> modelClass,
    int modelLayout, java.lang.Class<VH> viewHolderClass,
    com.firebase.client.Firebase ref)
```

and

```
FirebaseRecyclerViewAdapter(java.lang.Class<T> modelClass,
    int modelLayout, java.lang.Class<VH> viewHolderClass
    com.firebase.client.Query ref)
```

So this the are the only ways in which you can instantite the `FirebaseRecyclerViewAdapter` class, using a `Firebase Reference` or a `Query`.

Another way will be to create you own `MyRecyclerAdapter` in order to achieve that.

```
class MyRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerAdapter {/* ... */}
```

Comment: Yep, I've had to create my own recycler adapter in order to get what i needed.

Comment: Yes, that's corect. That's what i also mentioned in my updated answer.

Comment: Yes, well before you answered, but I've marked this for future reference.